# Google Map Api error - js?sensor=false

Tags: google-maps, drupal-7, google-geolocation

I'm french, my english is poor.. :F

I work with Drupal 7 and the module "Geolocation. I have created a map, a new field in a new type. I have configured the field..

the map does not display,

**"Small problem ... An error occurred Maps Google is not correctly loaded on this page. For more technical information on this error, please consult the Javascript console."**

**Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

**js?sensor=false (ligne 34)**

However i have added a API key in the module configuration. .

Somebody can help me ? It's crasy problem

Comment: As @Joyson said, you must provide an API key as of June 22. So if you added an API key in the configuration, your module isn't using that API key (properly) when building the Maps URL. Or you did not activate the Google Maps JavaScript API in Developer Console

Comment: i have actived all module for the geolocalosation. Where you can activate the Google Maps JavaScript API in Developer Console ?

Comment: When logged in, go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/maps_backend/overview. When that API is already enabled, your module is not using your API key (the right way).

Comment: it's enabled. You use Drupal 7 ?

Comment: i have just tested with a real site, not localhost, it's the same problem. .

Answer (score 4):

As of June 22, 2016 Google Maps V3 no longer support keyless access (any request that doesn't include an API key).

You can register for the key : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

and add it to your URL :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i have tested directly it on html and API key, it's right. i use Drupal 7, with a module, i don't understand why it doesn't work.